# Python Script TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Tags: python, unicode, typeerror, raw-input

I'm writing a simple script to search a .txt document for a search word. The script so far will:
• Prompt for a file name
• Prompt for a word to search for

The prompts work, followed by "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found". I've read other posts on this error, but can't identify why this is happening, so I can move on to the steps: 
• Open the file in Append mode
• Append (print) the number of lines the keyword appears on in the file.

Please note: *This worked until I added the user prompts.*

```
import sys
import os

f = file(raw_input("Enter filename: "), 'a')
name_file = raw_input("Input search terms, comma separated: ").lower().split(",")
my_file = open(name_file, "a")
#removed {open(name_file}[0] from above line
search = [x.strip(' ') for x in f]
count = {}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to open the keywords list?

Comment: Edited for clarity. I'm trying to search for a specific word in the file, I understand "keywords" has a different meaning.

Comment: I know that it appears that you got further by posting a dup, but please don't do this again. Normally, this question would be closed as a dup of your existing question, but this one is worded better and seems to have helped. In the future, just make edits to your existing question.

Comment: Thanks @LynnCrumbling, I was under the impression I could not edit the original question, and told it wasn't specific enough. Should I delete the original?

Comment: @Ender Sure, that would be a fine idea... Roomba would come along and delete it in a few days anyway (closed, and negative score question + answer), but cleaning up after yourself is always good :)

Comment: As an interesting side note, I see that the answerer of the other question did eventually self-delete...

Answer (score 1):

`string.split(",")`

returns a list of strings. i.e:

```
>>myString = "Hello buddy, how are you?"

>>myList = mystring.split(",")

>>myList
["Hello buddy"," how are you?"]
```

name_file is a list, and your code explodes because open expects a string as its first argument, not a list

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sys.argv.

You run a command:

```
$ myscript.py file.txt term1 term2 term3
```

Script:

```
import sys

print sys.argv
```

Output:

```
['./myscript.py', 'myscript.py', 'file.txt', 'term1', 'term2', 'term3']
```